# Why does Rick Deckard farm bees?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner-2049

In *Blade Runner 2049*, when K is walking through the ruins of Las Vegas, he finds a small honey farm--overcrowded, swarming with the bees, as if not touched very often.  The film as it unfolds after that, never explains that scene.  Deckard was clearly the only person living in Vegas at the time; is he farming honey just to nourish himself in that wasteland town?  Or is there some broader artistic reason for the swarming bugs?

Comment: Might be related to, "What's the Significance of Bees in Blade Runner 2049?" https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81250/what-is-the-significance-of-bees-in-blade-runner-2049

Comment: I would even say it's very much a duplicate of that question. It is, of course, still an interesting question nevertheless.